# Metric on connections and magic 20000 value added

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, networkmanager, manjaro

I have 3 types of network connection and I set manyally metric for each connection:

1. LAN cable, metric = 1 - `enp0s31f6`,
2. WiFi, metric = 100 - `wlp2s0`,
3. 4G/LTE modem, metric = 1000 - `wwp0s20f0u8c3`.

The reason for setting of metric is that I want to prioritise my connectivity based on the list above (the modem connection is metered). I also set `autoconnect` priority for each connection but according to [KDE#394364](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=394364#c1) this will not work as I expected so that’s why I tried to go the way by setting of the metric.

When each connection is activated, the system adds a strange value of 20000 to the metric.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         100.87.7.97     0.0.0.0         UG    1000   0        0 wwp0s20f0u8c3
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20200  0        0 wlp2s0
100.87.7.96     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     1000   0        0 wwp0s20f0u8c3
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     200    0        0 wlp2s0
```

.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    20001  0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 enp0s31f6
```

This value 20000 is not added always, or to be more precise, it gets changed after some time to the value which I set for the particular connection.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 enp0s31f6
```

Any idea why this is happening?

My system is Manjaro KDE running on 4.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the behavior of Network Manager from version 1.8, see commit: https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/6b7e9f9b225e81d365fd95901a88a7bc59c1eb39

It says:

> This makes it possible to retain Internet connectivity when multiple
>   devices have a default route, but one with the link type of a higher
>   priority can not reach the Internet.